# Circuit and condition

Tags: voltage, current, resistance, current-measurement

My son is trying to solve contest tasks in physics. Among the questions, I found the following one

[image]

Let me translate.

**Find measurements of current meters within the circuit, shown on the picture. Resistance of current meters to be considered as much lower than resistance of the resistors.**

Power source is 12 V, resistors from left to right: 1 Ohm, 2 Ohm, 2 Ohm.

I have some knowledge about electronics and circuit design, but this task astonished me. In my option:

- it is not correct to connect current meters this way, and current meters are having extremely low resistance, at the same time this their resistance is defined;
- if I would consider this circuit, as any stupid circuit can be built by the human, saying that "consider resistance of current meters to be much lower that resistance of resistors" does not help, and to calculate circuit current meters' resistances are required.

Do I miss anything?

Edit: following conversation and answers I redrawn the circuit - here it is
[image]

Comment: It looks at first like the current meters will short out the resistors, but that's not what's happening. It's okay to treat them as zero ohm in this circuit. If you redraw the circuit as a diamond (with the 2 ohm resistor across the middle), the circuit should make more sense.

Comment: I bet they're meant to be volt meters.

Comment: Andy, this was my first thought and was a source of astonishment. After reading the task several times I understood that this circuit with current meters is having right to exist, the only issue was definition (and lack of such) of the resistance of current meters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description is basically saying to consider the current meters ideal.  Ideal current meters don't drop any voltage, so appear to have 0 Ω resistance.  Real meters don't, of course, which can alter the measurement.

They are trying to make it easy for you by telling you it's OK to ignore the non-ideal resistance of the current meters.  Basically, proceed as if the current meters are ideal, meaning they look like dead shorts to the circuit.

Comment: Ok, I was confused by the task's statement about resistance of the current meters. Following your assumption, it appears that all resistors are in parallel, their total resistance is 0.5 Ohms, and both current meters will show 24A, correct?

Comment: Close, but note that each meter is measuring the current through *two* resistors, not all of them.

Comment: Oh, you are right! A2=12, A1=18 :)

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyVf3k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Re - drawing, yes, you get all resistors in parallel but part current goes through A1 (18A) and part current goes through A2 (12A).

In this configuration assuming A1 and A2 are 0 ohms, A1 would measure the   combined current into R2 and R3. A2 would measure the combined current through R1 and R2.

Comment: This task is actually not an easy one, and hopefully we learned something new considering it!

Comment: Was a tricky one!